# File not found with .htaccess file on Apache server

Tags: php, apache, centos

I have this .htaccess on my Windows dev machine and everything works fine

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/webserv/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule   ^login/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)$   login.php?par1=$1&par2=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```

When I upload it on my Centos server I get the error

```
404 The requested URL path_to_script/login.php was not found on this server.
```

I cannot understand why this is. The file is definitely there and I gave permissions 777.

I have checked if the .htaccess is actually used by adding rubbish in it and getting an internal error (500) which means that it is working.

Also when I use .htaccess to make restrictions on IPs that have access to the directory it works. mod_rewrite is loaded as shown in the phpinfo() I have tried.

I am at a loss here.

**EDIT**

I noticed that it tries to search in the base_path appending it to the root path e.g.

```
/path_to_script/path_to_script/login.php
```

And that is why it fails. How do I solve this?

Comment: windows is case-insensitive. Try to check differences in uppercase chars on your path.

Comment: I have checked this. I copied the path in the error message and did a less on the linux machine to make sure it finds it and it does.

Comment: try to add `RewriteBase /path_to_script` before Rewrite Rule

Comment: no dice. The error now is File does not exist: /svc/web/www/rootdir/docs/svc where /svc/web/www/rootdir/ is the basepath.

Comment: Where is the file login.php and where the .htaccess? I'm thinking at an open_basedir rule.

Comment: they are in the same dir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it but in a way that I am not sure I like. At least it works. If someone has a better solution I would be glad to see it.

```
RewriteRule   ^login/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)$   http://host/webserv/login.php?par1=$1&par2=$2
```

The reason I don't like this solution is because I does not give a pretty url. It just redirects.

I still do not understand why I get the root directory appended to the request if I instead write:

```
RewriteRule   ^login/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)$   login.php?par1=$1&par2=$2
```